# Как пробежаться по содержимому <div>

Tags: javascript

Есть div, содержимое которого заполняется javascript. Другим скриптом мне нужно пробежаться по содержимому этого div по очереди, чтобы из каждого вложенного div вытащить все что нужно

```
<div id="result">
  <div>
    <label>User 1</label><input type="text" id="1" value="11">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>User 5</label><input type="text" id="5" value="55">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>User 6</label><input type="text" id="8" value="88">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам подойдет [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не идеальный код, а в качестве примера:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('#result > div');

divs.forEach(function(el){
  let children = el.children,
      label = children[0],
      input = children[1];
      
      console.log(
        label.textContent, 
        input.getAttribute('type'),
        input.getAttribute('id'),
        input.getAttribute('value')
      );
});
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div>
    <label>User 1</label><input type="text" id="1" value="11">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>User 5</label><input type="text" id="5" value="55">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>User 6</label><input type="text" id="8" value="88">
  </div>
</div>
```